# C++ Type redefinition after including library in unreal engine

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, lib, redefinition

I have the folliwing problem. I downloaded the git repo of this unreal engine third party library ( https://github.com/nialna/libnoise-UE4-ready ) which is basically a ue4 64 bit port of the original libnoise c++ library.

I built it with all the steps described (installed mfc classes, built it in 64 bit etc..) and copied the .lib files and the include files to my game project. (As described) 
As soon as i include the lib in my project i get thr following errors:

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\ucrt\corecrt.h(134): error C2953: '_CrtEnableIf<true,_Ty>': class template has already been defined
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\corecrt.h(125): note: see declaration of '_CrtEnableIf<true,_Ty>'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\ucrt\corecrt.h(489): error C2011: '__crt_locale_data_public': 'struct' type redefinition
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\corecrt.h(455): note: see declaration of '__crt_locale_data_public'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\ucrt\corecrt.h(496): error C2011: '__crt_locale_pointers': 'struct' type redefinition
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\corecrt.h(462): note: see declaration of '__crt_locale_pointers'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\ucrt\corecrt.h(504): error C2011: '_Mbstatet': 'struct' type redefinition
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\corecrt.h(470): note: see declaration of '_Mbstatet'
```

It seems like this `corecrt.h` file gets included multiple times? And the other funny thing is there are 2 different windows SDK versions outputting the errors. (10.0.10240) and (10.0.17134.0) which could also explain why the files gets included twice.

I tried to delete the older sdk from my machine but it's even not listed in the visual studio installer, it's only jm the file system. I deleted it from there but i still got these errors.

I built the lib with different sdk versions... No change...
I already spent hours on this problem and i'm clueless right now.

Comment: I can't find `corecrt.h` file in git repo you linked. I guess your environment links SDK twice (if that's what the numbers indicate). Try investigating that further. Maybe try to move old SDK away, so it's not available?

Comment: The corecrt.h file is part of the windows sdk and it get's linked/included from there in the lib and apparently in ue4. (from my understanding at least).

i already tried to delete the old windows sdk. (deleted the C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0 folder). the funny thing is, that it's not "active" in the visual studio installer. ( i never installed it manually myself)

i event tried to install and uninstall it via VS installer. the 10.0.10240.0 folder even got created again autom.

and even right after i delted the folder, i got the some output from above.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by building the whole unreal engine from source on my machine with the same compiler as the library.